# Python ECDSA failing to verify signature

Tags: python, cryptography, bitcoin, ecdsa

**I am trying to verify a Bitcoin signature using ECDSA in python but finding it very hard, many attempts failed already.**

*The params:*

```
address: 33ELcBdg6W7parjGxNYUz5uHVHwPqopNjE

message: hzpPiNlB

signature(base64): I2fKdGNtR5owOWVoWchMVWwC/gf4qyYZ8G+kvuR7CaBhU/0SO149a3/ylBaiVWzfUoXI5HlgYPjkrptk0HfW1NQ=
```

Note: I have converted the signature from base64 to hexstring as that is required by ECDSA. Whenever I try to verify it, it says:

> Expected 64 byte signature (128 hexstring), provided 65 byte signature
> (130 hexstring)

I had a look at many stackoverflow questions about ECDSA but none of the answers were 100% relevant to my qs. Your help is appreciated guys.

**Update:** I have used Bitcoin Python package. Have done this first to get the public key & then verify:

```
pip install bitcoin

>>> message = 'hzpPiNlB'
>>> signature = 'I2fKdGNtR5owOWVoWchMVWwC/gf4qyYZ8G+kvuR7CaBhU/0SO149a3/ylBaiVWzfUoXI5HlgYPjkrptk0HfW1NQ='
>>> import bitcoin
>>> recover_key = bitcoin.ecdsa_recover(message, signature)
>>> print(recover_key)
04bbdd00bafea40bf7b268baff4ec7635a0b12e94542067cf4077369be938f7b733c731248b88bb0f8b14783247705e568effd54e57643fc827852cf77d0ed8313
>>> verify = bitcoin.ecdsa_verify(message, signature, recover_key)
>>> print(verify)
True
```

Although the recovered pubkey is wrong up its somehow passing True. When using the correct pubkey which I have extracted from wallet I am getting False as result of verifying the signature.

```
 >>> message = 'hzpPiNlB'
 >>> signature = 'I2fKdGNtR5owOWVoWchMVWwC/gf4qyYZ8G+kvuR7CaBhU/0SO149a3/ylBaiVWzfUoXI5HlgYPjkrptk0HfW1NQ='
 >>> pub_key = '0352ab1e8ef8553fb307ae8dcafd2395fd06e5ca882f0e27143cb15cf495cc435e'
 >>> import bitcoin
 >>> verify = bitcoin.ecdsa_verify(message, signature, pub_key)
 >>> print(verify)
 False
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code, so we can help you to deal with this problem.

Comment: Just guessing that you may try to use `ecdsa.util.sigdecode_string(s[1:], ...)` where `s`  is hex decoded signature.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg have updated the post, I am not getting hex error anymore, I am instead getting the wrong pubkey being recovered etc...

Comment: Actually, you ask a different question now. Also, your new code is not reproducible. Using pybitcointools `bitcoin.ecdsa_recover` yields `ValueError`. I think you should post another question and provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) incluring import statements.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg pip install bitcoin, then: import bitcoin

Comment: @YuriGinsburg I have figured it out. It was a path issue all along when extracting the Pubkey. My bad, its all good now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After extracting the `pubkey` by using the correct path, I can confirm that:

```
verify = bitcoin.ecdsa_verify(message, signature, pub_key).
```

is returning `True`.